# HTTPS checksum or payload checksum confusion

Tags: https, checksum, integrity

If the communication protocol is HTTPS, is adding checksum of any kind to the payload beneficial? to be exact.

1. Is it good to have checksum on the content body to ensure integrity?
2. Is it good to have checksum of files/multipart content to ensure integrity?
3. Both 1 & 2 is good to have
4. Neither is necessary

I am thinking more in terms of web services only.

Comment: I may have a possible answer. Checksum is not necessary. Error checks like these is built into SSL ofcourse but I  can't recall the context of this question. Since the question gets quite a few views I thought I should come back and answer...... like 4 years later :/ Maybe I am wiser and stuff